# How to publish a ASP.net project?

Tags: asp.net, publish

i'm trying to publish my website project that i've made in Asp .net. I upload all files to my ftp folder but when i go to my website http://smile2013.host-ed.me/test/ i get this error " Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) "

Comment: Could you maybe post some more info on your configuration? You have IIS running on the server? Does the site work locally?

Comment: host-ed.me runs ASP.NET 2.0 using Mono. They only have Linux servers. So.. is your code .NET 2.0 and Mono compatible?

Comment: thank you guys for the fast reply, the site work locally, probably like @David said my project is not in .Net 2.0. Now i verify this.

Comment: Thank you David for the solution! my project is coded in .NET 4.0!

Comment: Right click on the project > Properties > tab "Application" > Target Framework.
I'd worry more about it being Mono compatible.
The easiest solution would be to choose a Windows host.